# Python web drivers

Tags: javascript, python

Im trying to scrape products from a web store similar to how [Dropified](http://www.dropified.com/) scrapes items from Ali express,

Current Solution(the way it's set up it will only try and access the first item):

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import re

# Get search inputs from user
search_term = raw_input('Search Term:')

# Build URL to imdb.com
aliURL = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=%(q)s'
payload = {'q': search_term, }

# Get resulting webpage
r = requests.get(aliURL % payload)

# Build 'soup' from webpage and filter down to the results of search
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
titles = soup.findAll('a', attrs = {'class': 'product'})


itemURL = titles[0]["href"]
seperatemarker = '?'
seperatedURL = itemURL.split(seperatemarker, 1)[0]

seperatedURL = "http:" + seperatedURL

print seperatedURL

IR = requests.get(seperatedURL)
Isoup = BeautifulSoup(IR.text, "html5lib")

productname = Isoup.findAll('h1')

print productname
```

This solution works assuming that the items on the page don't require javascript if the item does it will only retrieve the initial page before the document is ready.

I realise I can use a python web driver, but I was wondering if there was any other solution to this problem that would allow for easy automation of a web scraping tool.

Comment: Why can't you use `time.sleep(30)`, and wait for the JS to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `selenium` with `phantomjs`. `selenium` and `phantomjs` handle most of the issues related to JS generated content on the page. You don't even need to think about these things anymore.
If you're scraping many pages and want to speed things up, you might want to do things asynchronously. For a small to mid-sized setup, you can use `RQ`. For larger projects you can use `celery`. What these tools allow you to do is scrape multiple pages at the same time(not concurrently though).
Note that the tools I've mentioned so far have nothing to do with `asyncio` or other `async` frameworks.
I tried scraping some e-commerce pages and noticed that the program was spending 80% of its time waiting for HTTP calls to return something. Using the above tools you can reduce that 80% to 10% or less.